# SCCM 2012 Query Deployment Type

Tags: sql, sccm

I'm looking into the SCCM SQL database and I'm trying to query out the install command set for the deployment type but so far I cannot find it... Is there anyone knows what table/s I need to query to find this? v_Program is not the table that stores it... :(

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have not been able to find a solution to this, it seems that `fn_ListDeploymentTypeCIs(@LocaleID)` is the SQL function that will return the *Application* Deployment Type details. It works best when married (`INNER JOIN`) with `fn_ListLatestApplicationCIs(@LocaleID)`. 
Hat tip to Anoop Mannur with [this article](http://anoopcnair.com/2012/05/07/configmgr-sccm-2012-custom-reports-for-list-of-applications-deployment-types-and-content-source/) that I stumbled across which referenced these SQL functions; only took 2 hours of schema analysis, Google'ing, and general query bashing to find the data I was hunting for :/.

If you have a look inside the function definition, it references a whole host of functions, views, and tables (no wonder it is so hard to get the info!!!) like:

- `fn_ListCIs(@LocaleID)`
- `appdtrelation`
- `vSMS_ConfigurationItems`
- `CI_ApplicationModelInfo`
- ... and a bunch of nested queries referencing other tables

It really is a fine example of targeted relational data structures!

I hope you have been able to find an alternate solution; if not I hope that this can help!